# systemd to control launch order for services

Tags: systemd-unit

I have two systemd service files. I want `gw_web.service` to start after `gw_log.service`.

Here are the two service files:

`gw_log.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=myGarage Log Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
User=pi
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rm /home/pi/myprojects/myGarage/gw_log.service.log
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/myprojects/myGarage/gw_log.py
StandardOutput=file:/home/pi/myprojects/myGarage/gw_log.service.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`gw_web.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=myGarage Web Service
Requires=gw_log.service
After=gw_log.service

[Service]
Type=idle
User=pi
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rm /home/pi/myprojects/myGarage/gw_web.service.log
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/myprojects/myGarage/gw_web.py
StandardOutput=file:/home/pi/myprojects/myGarage/gw_web.service.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I reboot the server, only `gw_log.service` is active. `gw_web.service` is dead. If I `systemctl start gw_web` then everything works. But it doesn't work on boot up.

I have disabled and re-enabled the services - no joy. What am I doing wrong?

Update: gw_web.service wouldn't start because there was an ordering cycle on gw_web.service/start and multi-user.target/start.  I resolved the problem by adding `DefaultDependencies=no` to the Unit section in `gw_web.service`

Comment: If `gw_web.service` is enabled to start on boot, there should be some error as to why it did not start.  If `gw_web.service` requires the network to be configured to start correctly, then you should list `network-online.target` as a required dependency in addition to `gw_log.service`.  If there are any other services that are required to be running before `gw_web.service`, those should also be specified as dependencies.

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding `DefaultDependencies=no` to the Unit section of `gw_web.service`